# R Data table setkey - error some columns are not in the data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to use data.table `setkey` with pre-defined lists `id` and `categories`, but get an error message:

```
> setkey(tr_id_cat_dt, id, categories)
Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose) : 
  some columns are not in the data.table: categories
```

I would like all the elements of `id` and `categories` to appear as keys.

Is this possible?

---

id and categorie are lists of values, for example:

```
categories = c(9115L, 9909L, 3203L, 5558L, 4401L, 1703L, 1726L, 3504L, 3509L, 
5122L, 5616L, 5619L, 2202L, 2119L, 6202L, 5824L, 799L, 4517L, 
7205L, 706L)


dput(head(tr_id_cat_dt))
structure(list(id = c(86246, 86246, 86246, 86246, 86246, 86246
    ), category = c(706L, 706L, 706L, 706L, 706L, 706L)), .Names = c("id", 
    "category"), sorted = c("id", "category"), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x015424a0>)
```

Comment: would `setkey(tr_id_cat_dt, c("id", "categories"))` work? or `setkeyv(tr_id_cat_dt, c("id", "categories"))`

Comment: id and categories are actually lists of values. I added some details.

Comment: Show `dput(head(tr_id_cat_dt))`. Is `categories` a column in the data.table?

Comment: yes categories is a column in tr_id_cat_dt

Comment: Look at the structure output by `dput`: your `categories` column is actually called `category`.

Comment: @Scott Richie Yes, but I do not want to use the values in tr_id_cat_dt$category, I want to use the values in categories as the keys.

Comment: You can only use a column of the data.table as a key.

Comment: @Roland I see. How about creating a second data.table with my own set of keys, and copying the data for equal keys? Is that feasible?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to join two data.tables?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense as currently written. `tr_id_cat_dt$category` seems to be an integer not a categorical. Is the list `categories` supposed to be a list of all its levels? (Either way, the interpreter can't magically know that they're related). Instead of declaring `categories` as a variable, why not convert `tr_id_cat_dt$category` to an actual categorical like `factor(tr_id_cat_dt$category, levels=categories, ...)` ? Or do you want to keep column `category` and also add column `categories`, if so how? Anyway, `setkey()` only says which columns are keys, not add/infer cols.

Answer (score 3):

You can `setkey` only on the columns of a `data.table` (as @Roland already pointed out).

```
require(data.table)
DT = data.table(x = 1:2, y=3:4)
z = 5:6
setkey(DT, x) # works
setkey(DT, z) # doesn't
# Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
#   some columns are not in the data.table: z

setkey(DT[, z := z], z) # works
```

HTH